# Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String?' in type cast

Tags: flutter, flutter-video-player

I get the ERROR Unhandled Exception: type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'String?' in IOS only and that too not in every video. Some of the other videos get picked without any error.In android it works fine without any error. What could it be? Pls help..

```
   Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String?' in type cast
   #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod 
   (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:158:41)
   <asynchronous suspension>
   #1      MethodChannelImagePicker.getVideo(package:image_picker_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_.           channel_image_picker.dart:220:26)
   <asynchronous suspension>  
   #2      _AddVideo2.pickVideo (package:flutterapp/media/addVideo2.dart:29:21)
```

And Error takes me to this:-

```
  final video = (error)await ImagePicker()
      .pickVideo(source: source, maxDuration:
```

Full Code:-

```
  class AddVideo2 extends StatefulWidget {
  final String videoFrom;

  const AddVideo2({Key key, @required this.videoFrom}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _AddVideo2 createState() => _AddVideo2();
}

class _AddVideo2 extends State<AddVideo2> {
  
  

   pickVideo(ImageSource source) async {
    //Navigator.pop(context);
    if (storagePermission) {
      final video = await ImagePicker()
          .pickVideo(source: source, maxDuration:
      Duration(seconds: 60));
      if (video == null) {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: "No Video Selected!!".tr(),
            );
      } else {
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => ConfirmVideo(
                      videofile: File(video.path),
                      imageSource: source,
                      videoFrom: widget.videoFrom,
                    )));
      }
    } 
  }

  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("Video From: ${widget.videoFrom}");
    
  }

}
```

Comment: Could you at least post the whole code snippet? That is not even a fraction. What is `(error)`, what is `source`, why does your code end in a syntax error? We cannot help with that, you need at least post a reasonable part of your code.

Comment: updated. Pls check.

Comment: Can you print `source`? Maybe the problem lies in that variable

Comment: ImageSource.gallery